# Diffeomorphisms that permute angles?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, permutations, manifolds, diffeomorphism

I'm new to manifolds. I'm reading "An Intro to Manifolds" by Tu, when I can. A diffeomorphism is a conformal map if the pullback of the metric results in a conformally equivalent metric.

> Are there any references about diffeomorphisms that permute angles (not conformal)? (If this is impossible, please help me understand why?)

A diffeomorphism in $\Bbb R^2,$ from a surface to a surface, $f:(0,1)^2\to (0,1)^2$ that permutes angles should take the original set of angles and reorder them so that an arbitrary angle $\theta$ between two curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ with intersection at point $p,$ is now located at a new point $p'\ne p.$

Notice below how the four angles are the same when considered as sets but have been permuted/re-arranged.

[image]

Like I said I'm not sure if this notion is possible.

Comment: A conformal map preserve angles between tangent vectors. Therefore if you have two differentiable curves intersecting at a point, the angle between their tangent vectors at that point is the same when you look at the tangent vectors of the curves obtained after applying the conformal map.

Comment: At least if you use the standard definition of angle coming from the Cauchy Schwartz inequality.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand; it is somewhat imprecise and vague. First, I take it that your highlighted question is concerned with diffeomorphisms that are not conformal? Second, your explanation of that it means to "permute angles" does not help much: it is "always* true that if $p \in \gamma_1 \cap \gamma_2$ then $p'=f(p) \in f(\gamma) \cap f(\gamma_2)$.

Comment: One could then measure the angle between the tangent lines $T_p\gamma_1$ and $T_p\gamma_2$, and also the angle between the tangent lines $T_{f(p)}f(\gamma_1)$ and $T_{f(p)} f(\gamma_2)$ and one could compare those angles, perhaps by subtracting them or something like that, I dunno, and study the result of this comparison as the curves and their intersection points vary. Is that sort of what you have in mind?

Comment: @LeeMosher yes diffeomorphisms that are not conformal. And what I had pictured was a grid in $(0,1)^2.$ Say before the transformation you measure all angles between gridlines, and you get, 30 degrees, 42 degrees and 37 degrees for example. Then you perform the diffeomorphism and measure all angles again and get the same angles, but in different locations. I will include a small image.

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvote?

Comment: I agree the question is vague, but I don't dislike it. It's hard to tell what kind of 'permutations' between angles you are willing to allow, though. Should all points of the manifold be subject to the same 'rule'? Maybe the notion of a [quasiconformal mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconformal_mapping) might be interesting for you.

Comment: This is happening at precisely one point? You should first understand why $\theta_1=\theta_3$ and $\theta_2=\theta_4$. In the plane you can do this with a linear map fixing the point. On a Riemannian surface, you can do the linear map on the tangent plane and then exponentiate. P.S. The linear map/diffeomorphism will reverse orientation.

Comment: While I did not downvote myself, the imprecision of your original question could easily be a good reason for someone to downvote; I might eventually have downvoted myself, had you not worked on making your question more mathematically precise.

Comment: To answer your actual question, I know of no references on this topic. Differential geometers are usually more interested in the angles between tangent lines, as suggested in my earlier comment.